# Scheme url to open ios aplication with parameters

Tags: swift, url, token

I have an application in Swift which has the function of "I forgot my password", which sends a URL in the user's email, in that URL contains user and token

Example:
https://example.com/forgotPassword#/user/token
[image]

Clicking the "https://example.com/forgotPassword#/user/token" link requires the application to open when the link is clicked by passing the parameters after the # (user / token) as follows in the example.

I need to click on the link and open the application.

I tried to modify the `info p list` in xcode but it generates a link example: application: //, me limiting to send it by email for example, could anyone help me please? If you have not understood, I can explain it better, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the *word* "scheme" in your question title but your example doesn't use a scheme. Well, it does use a scheme, but the scheme is `https`, which is a link. You need *your app* to define and declare its *own* scheme.